# How can I record a video call in Janus?

Tags: recording, janus-gateway

I added a "REC" button in the video call which on click does the following request:

```
videocall.send({"message": { "request": "set", "record" : true, "filename" : "/opt/janus/share/janus/recordings/1111" }});
```

[This guide](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/janus__videocall_8c.html) explains that

> record enables or disables the recording of this peer; in case recording is enabled, filename allows to specify a basepath/filename to use for the file (-audio.mjr and -video.mjr are automatically appended)

I tried the video call. The audio and video mjr files are actually created in the specified path under the specified name. Then (I still don't know what other way could I play them) I add manually a .nfo file to read them with the plugin "Recorder/Playout" - it works fine with records from the Video Room - but when I open the record from the list it appears the message "Error opening recording files" and in the terminal where janus is running these errors and warnings appear:

> [ERR] [plugins/janus_recordplay.c:janus_recordplay_get_frames:1607]
>   Invalid header...
>
> [WARN] Error opening audio recording, trying to go
>   on anyway
>
> [ERR]
>   [plugins/janus_recordplay.c:janus_recordplay_get_frames:1607] Invalid
>   header...
>
> [WARN] Error opening video recording, trying to go on anyway

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Do you still face this issue?

Comment: So did you fix it?

Comment: Have you enabled the record plugin on the js? you can't record in that videocalltest.js you have to add the plugin first. see the record js to compare it